# Lightweight Render Pipeline in Unity turned everything pink

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently added Lightweight Render Pipeline in my existing Unity project and converted all materials to lightweight. But it always result a pink material.

Unity Version: 2018.2.02f Personal

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution to fix this problem. Real problem was that I missed lightweight pipeline asset.

After creating lightweight pipeline asset and assigning it to graphics setting solved my problem.

Solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37EokvVEXJo

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by choosing Assets > Reimport All.