# Objects graphic messed up when adding lightweight render pipeline

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I built a portal shader and it required me to use Lightweight Render Pipeline. i upgraded all the object materials to lightweight materials and i created a lightweight renderrer pipeline and put it in the graphics settings. Althoug,still some of the objects are pink. is there any way to fix it?
Thank you
 [image]

I did what they said in "Lightweight Render Pipeline in Unity turned everything pink" but still then some of the objects left pink.

Sorry about this short qeustion, i am new at it. If you dont unsderstand my question feel free to ask

Edit: 
Ruzihm solution was working for me, thanks him :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lightweight Render Pipeline in Unity turned everything pink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600561/lightweight-render-pipeline-in-unity-turned-everything-pink)

Comment: No, i looked at it and i did what they say. Although even after this some of the objects left pink

Comment: Its specifically the terrain and some more objects that are still pink

Comment: What shaders are on the material of the terrain and the other pink objects?

Comment: some of them have standart shaders, the non terrains, and i dont know what about the terrain

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Your solution was working for me for the terrain part. The other objects i just re-imported. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Whenever you see magenta (rgb(1,0,1)) in the viewport, unless you have, for some reason, specifically requested it, it indicates a shader or material error. Unity specifically does this so that the errors make themselves immmediately obvious. If you find the shader in the project view and select it, you can see any compilation errors in the inspector. But, as was previously mentioned, this looks like you're trying to use a feature not available in LWRP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using shaders that are incompatible with the LWRP. The Unity Editor can try to automatically replace them with compatible ones. In the menu, do **Edit -> Render Pipeline -> Upgrade Project Materials to LightweightRP Materials**, and then Unity will do its best to upgrade the materials/shaders.

This may be only a partial solution depending on if Unity can find a suitable replacement for all of your shaders or not.

For the ones Unity can't or won't upgrade, you can try configuring them with default LWRP shaders by inspecting the material on those objects, clicking **Shader**, and then selecting **Lightweight Render Pipeline > Lit** or **Lightweight Render Pipeline > Unlit** depending on if you want lighting effects or not.

For the terrain, you can replace its current material with the **TerrainLit** material:

Where to set it:
[image: where to set terrain lit]

Where to find it:
[image: where to find the terrain lit]
[[images source]](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-terrain-layers-not-working-with-lwrp-in-upgraded-project.646789/)

Comment: Thanks, but i tried that already, it only fixed some of them but it didnt fix the others

Comment: @shaked I added some info about manually replacing shaders & materials. let me know if that helps